# Purging observations from a dataset based on number of occurrences

Tags: r

I have a data frame in which one variable is categorical and has a large number of possible values.  I'm trying to process this data frame in a way that removes any instance of a categorical variable that occurs fewer than X number of times.

For example, if I'm dealing with car makes as the variable, it may look like:

```
Toyota
Ford
Lexus
Ford
Acura
Subaru
Dodge
Ford
Ford
Lexus
...
...
...
```

I would like to remove all observations in which the car make classifier occurs fewer than ten times.  For example, if Ford, Lexus, and Toyota appear 30, 20, and 15 times, and all others fewer than ten, I would like to remove all other entries associated with those makes.

I know that a command like

```
cars.processed <- which(table(cars$make) > 10)
```

does produce a an integer count of how many classifiers meet the required criteria, but I don't know how to move on from there.

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lets Assume that `DF` is your data.frame and `x` is the column in questions and `thr` is your threshold:

```
thr <- 3
keep <- names(which(table(DF$x) > thr))
DF   <- DF[DF$x %in% keep, ]

# optionally, drop levels
DF$x <- droplevels(DF$x)
```

Here is a data.table solution as well:

```
library(data.table)

DT <- data.table(DF)

DT[x %in% names(which(table(x)>thr))]
```

Or if you dont mind reordering your rows according to x, it gets even more succinct

```
DT <- data.table(DF, key="x")

DT[.(names(which(table(x)>thr)))]
```

Comment: You don't need `droplevels` on an individual vector; `DF <- droplevels(DF)` will work, assuming you want all unused factors levels in the `DF` dropped.

Comment: @GavinSimpson, Personally, I dont like calling `droplevels` on a whole data.frame as I often find myself using the levels of a factor column to help count for what is absent as well as what is present.

Comment: Great - thanks guys, appreciate it.  I have one more question: my response variable is technically a binary variable (for example, 'good' and 'bad') however the function I'm calling requires it to be numeric {0,1} - is there an elegant way to do this? as.numeric() makes it {1,2}.

Comment: Awesome - too easy.  Sometimes the answer is right under your nose.  Thanks again.